# E: Package 'dkms' has no installation candidate

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I installed Kali 2.0 on an Oracle VirtualBox. Everything was going fine until I tried to run the command

```
apt-get -y install dkms
```

This gave me the following error message

```
Package dkms is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'dkms' has no installation canidate
```

Here's the output I get when I run

```
apt-cache policy
```

[image]

Why am I getting an this error message and how do I fix it?

I'm a newcomer to both Linux and Kali, so [this is the guide](https://youtu.be/Rka5MqnCn1E?t=9m45s) I was following. I hit this error at around 9:45 in the video.

Comment: Please paste the output of `apt-cache policy` into your question. `dkms` is available on Debian, at least.

Comment: Try `apt-cache search 'dkms*'`, maybe the

Answer (score 1):

You have only the *update* repository enabled, so enable the full release repository.

1. Add this line

   ```
   deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
   ```

   To

   ```
   /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Update package list

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install DKMS

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dkms
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The no.1 top awnser is correct for kali sana, for ANY kali, do this:
Navigate to /ect/apt and find sources.list
Open the file useing a text editor and create a new line at the bottom of the document.
Inside that file you should see somthing like this:

## deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2018.2 *Kali-rolling* - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20180412-10:55]/ kali-last-snapshot contrib main non-free

For me, i would put 
deb http://http.kali.org/ Kali-last-snapshot main contrib non-free

Use whatever it says for you, this is the only way it worked for me.